# CSV File reading problem - Why does this code only properly read the first traverse into a list but not the 2nd set of data and 3rd ones?

Tags: python, csv

so basically I'm doing a practice for reading a CSV file of the fire accident happened around the world, and then plot them on the map. During the process, I was reading the data using the CSV module, however, only the "Lats" are properly added to the list, the following list "Lons" and "Brightness" Appeared to be an empty list... Does anyone knows why?

```
from plotly.graph_objs import Scattergeo, Layout
from plotly import offline
filename = 'data/MODIS_C6_1_Global_24h.csv'

with open(filename) as f:

    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header_row = next(reader)
    print(header_row)
    # 1. I think we have to get the latitude values out first.
    lats = [row[0] for row in reader]
    lons = [row[1] for row in reader]
    brightness = [row[2] for row in reader]

print(lats)
print(lons)
print(brightness)
```

If you need a reference to see how the CSV file looks like, here is a reference link:
[World_Fire.csv](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ehmatthes/pcc_2e/master/chapter_16/mapping_global_data_sets/data/world_fires_1_day.csv)

Comment: So, If i print(lats) Ouput: [123, 32, 12, etc...] set of data. but if i print (lons) or (brightness): [] it shows an empty list.

Comment: Because you exhausted it while doing `[row[0] for row in reader]`. The `reader` is exhausted now. You will need to read it again.

Comment: `lats, long, bright = (row[0], row[1], row[2]) for row in reader`

Comment: Wow，Thank you, this actually really helps me and fixed the problem! Can you explain to me a little bit more about exhausted though please? What is exhausted for the reader? Thank you so much for you help!

Comment: Okay guys, so basically it's because the reader is a generator, it only produce the data once, that's why we can't loop through it like that!